# App is not verified when using Google Provider in firebase login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I used `firebase.auth.signInWithPopup()` from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#popup-mode) documentation. However, I am getting this warning on the popup window saying that my app isn't verified yet. See image below.

I don't know where to start from here since as far as I can remember, I can't find anything about this on the firebase auth docs. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the Google provider from the `Authentication` page within firebase?

Comment: @sketchthat That was like the first thing I did. Thanks

Comment: Figured as much, was hoping it was an easy fix - I guess not!. I haven't seen that error before...

Comment: @sketchthat I think google added a app review now. Before you get verified you have to get your app reviewed and approved by google. I don't know tho if firebase should be exempted to that or something, I was hoping. You can see the review process here https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?authuser=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google now requires apps be verified when you request certain sensitive data: 
https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/new-security-protections-to-reduce-risk.html

Firebase is not exempt. Why should it be? Any attacker can create a Firebase account with Google provider enabled and try to phish Google users with it.

Comment: Thanks. :) I got my app approved yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your app through this link [OAuth consent screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?visit_id=637096703063584275-3713927127&rd=1&project=wishooo-backend&folder&organizationId&duration=P1D)